# batchsize option in pyspark dataframe.write() is not working

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, batchsize

I am trying to write data from pyspark to postgresql DB. I used the batchsize 1000 and total data in pyspark dataframe is 10000. But the insertion being made in postgresql is not in batches. It is inserting data one by one. 
Following code is used to write  into DB

```
        df.write.
            option('batchsize',1000).jdbc(
            url=database_connection.url,
            table=data_table,
            mode="append",
            properties=database_connection.properties
        )
```

Kindly suggest some solution . Is this option work for POSTGRESQL Db ?

Answer (score 0):

depending upon the resources(cores) you are using it is paralleling the data load with bulk load. batch is processed internally while fetching it from the HDFS Table but not while writing it to the table. this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2018/05/12/turbo-boost-data-loads-from-spark-using-sql-spark-connector/) might help you understand this.